# Installing Nvidia drivers on ThinkPad w530

Tags: graphics, thinkpad

I am on a ThinkPad W530 and have just installed Ubuntu. Which one of these drivers do I install?

Does the command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` install current drivers?

[image]

**EDIT**: I used `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` and now there is a nvidia_304 driver activated in Additional Drivers:

If you have Optimus enabled in the BIOS, you either have to **disable** it or install **Bumblebee**

[image]

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question. Please move the answer from the question to the answer area.

Comment: This does not look like a dupe of the suggested question. The answers there are about getting the very latest drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`. There should be a new driver that appears in the Additional Drivers GUI. Restart your computer.

If you have Optimus enabled in the BIOS, you either have to disable it or **install Bumblebee**. Otherwise, you will have grey icons on the dashboard.

Comment: In my case the system would hang after GRUB using nVidia. Nouveau works, but nouveau is really a mess when using virtual machines.